# how to replace all the email id records with progress 4gl

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

```
The problem here is I want to update the email ids, I want to update like user@abc.com to user@xyz.com
```

I have selected all the email ids like this,

```
for each table where 
 table.email matches "*" + "@abc.com" + "*" no-lock :
    Display
```

I can't use replace function, since each email ids will be of different length.
 Is it possible to change email ids like this ? Please share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing exactly "abc" with "xyz" is done like this:

```
/* You need to change NO-LOCK to EXCLUSIVE-LOCK if you want to update or change! */
FOR EACH table WHERE table.email MATHES"*" + "@abc.com" + "*" EXCLUSIVE-LOCK:
  ASSIGN
    table.email = REPLACE(table.email, "@abc.com", "@xyz.com").
END.
```

But maybe you need to elaborate your question or is this all you want to do?

**About performance**

This query wont be very fast. Matches does not utilize any indices so the entire table will be scanned.
On later versions of Progress you can add a `TABLE-SCAN` option. This will increase speed but not by a lot. If you do this you will have to remove the MATCHES expression in the query and do like this:

```
FOR EACH table EXCLUSIVE-LOCK TABLE-SCAN:
  IF table.email MATCHES etcetera
  END.
END.
```

If this is a one time thing to fix e-mail addresses perhaps it doesn't need to  be that fast? If not I suggest you add a logical field to the table (table.fixed) and create an index with the field in it. Then you can very fast go through all not fixed records.

Comment: I just replaced it like this,

Answer (score 0):

I tried myself, and I wrote like this, and it worked.

```
def var cmail1 as char.
def var cmail2 as char.
assign
cmail1 = "@abc.com"
cmail2  = "@xyz.com".



for each table where
exclusive-lock :
Assign
table.email = REPLACE(table.email, cmail1, cmail2).
```

but the performance is low. If you any alternate for this, please post.

Comment: Since your scanning the entire table (MATCHES wont utilize any index) it will be slow. If your on a newer version of Progress you can add TABLE-SCAN at the end of the FOR EACH but it wont make a very large difference!